# Nexflow only processes one of my paired sample in a subworkflow

Tags: nextflow

I have a workflow consisting of 2 subworkflows.

```
params.reads = "$projectDir/data/raw/reads/*_{1,2}.fastq.gz"
params.kaiju_db = "$projectDir/data/kaijudb/viruses/kaiju_db_viruses.fmi"
params.kaiju_names = "$projectDir/data/kaijudb/viruses/names.dmp"
params.kaiju_nodes = "$projectDir/data/kaijudb/viruses/nodes.dmp"

workflow subworkflow_A {

  take:
    reads                                      // channel: [ val(sample), [ reads ] ]

  main:
    count_reads(reads)
    trim_reads(reads)

  emit:
    trimmed_reads = process2.out.reads      // channel: [ val(sample), [ trimmed_reads ] ]
}

workflow subworkflow_B {

  take:
    reads                                      // channel: [ val(sample), [ reads ] ]
    db            // channel: /path/to/kaiju/db.fmi
    nodes         // channel: /path/to/kaiju/nodes/file
    names         // channel: /path/to/kaiju/names/file

  main:
    taxonomic_classification(reads, nodes, db)
    kaiju_to_krona(taxonomic_classification.out, nodes, names)
    krona_import_text(kaiju_to_krona.out)
    kaiju_to_table(taxonomic_classification.out, nodes, names)
}

workflow main {
    ch_reads = Channel.fromFilePairs("$params.reads", checkIfExists:true)
    subworkflow_A(ch_reads)
    
    ch_db = Channel.fromPath("$params.kaiju_db", checkIfExists: true)
    ch_nodes = Channel.fromPath("$params.kaiju_nodes", checkIfExists: true)
    ch_names = Channel.fromPath("$params.kaiju_names", checkIfExists: true)
    ch_trimmed_reads = subworkflow_A.out.trimmed_reads
    subworkflow_B(ch_processed_reads, ch_db, ch_nodes, ch_names)
}
```

The input for `params.reads` is a directory like,

```
reads/
├── test_sample1_1.fastq.gz
├── test_sample1_2.fastq.gz
├── test_sample2_1.fastq.gz
└── test_sample2_2.fastq.gz
```

The input for `subworkflow_A`, `ch_reads` is:

```
[test_sample1, [~project/data/raw/reads/test_sample1_1.fastq.gz, ~project/data/raw/reads/test_sample1_2.fastq.gz]]
[test_sample2, [~project/data/raw/reads/test_sample2_1.fastq.gz, ~project/data/raw/reads/test_sample2_2.fastq.gz]]
```

`subworkflow_A` then emits the following channel into `ch_trimmed_reads`

```
[test_sample1, [~project/work/51/240e81f0a30e7e4c1d932abfe97502/test_sample1.trim.R1.fq.gz, ~project/work/51/240e81f0a30e7e4c1d932abfe97502/test_sample1.trim.R2.fq.gz]]
[test_sample2, [~project/work/work/b2/d38399833f3adf11d4e8c6d85ec293/test_sample2.trim.R1.fq.gz, ~project/work/b2/d38399833f3adf11d4e8c6d85ec293/test_sample2.trim.R2.fq.gz]]
```

For some reason, `subworkflow_B` only runs the first sample `test_sample1`, and not the second sample `test_sample1` when I want to run it over both samples.

Comment: I suspect this might have something to do with the components of `subworkflow_B`. Would you be able to edit your question to include the `process3` and `process4` process definitions? Also, if the inputs and outputs of `subworkflow_A` are basically the same, can your reproduce the problem without `subworkflow_A`?

Comment: Even if I run just `subworkflow_B` in isolation; it just runs one of file pairs. Alos, the processes `count_reads` and `trimmed_reads` both take the same input as well as `kaiju_to_krona` and `kaiju_to_table` if that is any help.

Comment: So `subworkflow_B` takes `reads`, `db`, `nodes`, and `names`. How are you really calling it in your main workflow block? Where do `db`, `nodes`, and `names` come from? If these are [queue channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel), you'll get the behavior you're seeing. These need to be [value channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) so that they can be used over and over again without being consumed.

Comment: Oh my apologies the other inputs are from channels as well, I just forgot to add them to my mock script above.

Comment: No worries - if you could show how they're being created and passed in to the caller (i.e. `subworkflow_B(ch_processed_reads, db, nodes, names)`), that would be super, thanks!

Comment: Updated my example script

Comment: Looks like I can convert `ch_db` from a queue to a value channel by doing something like `ch_db = Channel.fromPath("$params.kaiju_db", checkIfExists: true).first()`; I am testing this locally now and it worked, testing on a larger set of samples on AWS now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) is implicitly created by a process when it is invoked with a simple value. This means you can just pass in a plain `file` object. For example:

```
workflow main {
    ch_reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads, checkIfExists:true )

    db = file( params.kaiju_db )
    nodes = file( params.kaiju_nodes )
    names = file( params.kaiju_names )

    subworkflow_B( ch_reads, db, nodes, names )
}
```

Most of the time, what you want is one [queue](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#queue-channel) channel and one or more [value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#value-channel) channels when your process requires [multiple input channels](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#process-multiple-input-channels):

> When two or more channels are declared as process inputs, the process
> waits until there is a complete input configuration, i.e. until it
> receives a value from each input channel. When this condition is
> satisfied, the process consumes a value from each channel and launches
> a new task, repeating this logic until one or more channels are empty.
>
> As a result, channel values are consumed sequentially and any empty
> channel will cause the process to wait, even if the other channels
> have values.
>
> A different semantic is applied when using a [value channel](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-type-value). This kind
> of channel is created by the [Channel.value](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#channel-value) factory method or
> implicitly when a process is invoked with an argument that is not a
> channel. By definition, a value channel is bound to a single value and
> it can be read an unlimited number of times without consuming its
> content. Therefore, when mixing a value channel with one or more
> (queue) channels, it does not affect the process termination because
> the underlying value is applied repeatedly.